# Authlib module not found on bmc control-m

Tags: python-3.x, cryptography, modulenotfounderror, control-m, authlib

I am running a code with uses authlib module and it runs fine with all dependency met but when I try to automate it through bmc control-m it gives module not found error. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So the issue is resolved I installed the authlib and cryptography modules by running the shell as administrator on prod server.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same userid for the Control-M job as when running directly? Also, verify the running mode of the Control-M Agent - does it run as root or via a fixed userid?

Comment: I am not using the same userid for the control-M job, I ran the script directly on server using the windows server service account control-m agent runs via a fixed userid